# AS3 Loop Movement on TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN

Tags: actionscript-3, touch

[My Code](http://pastebin.com/DPkAjctZ)

Edit: Apologies for having my code in an external link, but it would have been way too big.

I've been using this code to try and get my character to move in a certain direction and continue moving while the screen is still punched. I can properly calculate the direction I need to go in, but the trouble is that this code freezes up.

Anyone got any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'while' loop is locking you up because there's no way out within the scope of it's function. It's so busy looping that the compiler can't act on the MOUSE_UP.
If you put a trace in there instead of the call to `moveCharacter()` you'll see what I mean. Just wait until the debug compiler gives up, in about 15 sec. and prints out a thousand traces and then your 'screen released.'

This will work, using ENTER_FRAME loops instead of 'while':

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends Sprite
        {
                public var MySprite:Sprite;
                public var touchDown:Boolean;
                var MySpriteImage:Sprite = new redSprite;

                public function Main():void
                {
                        MySprite = new Sprite();
                        MySprite.x = 200;
                        MySprite.y = 200;

                        var world:Sprite = new Sprite();

                        //world.width = 320;
                        //world.height = 480;
                        addChild (world);

                        MySprite.addChild(MySpriteImage);

                        world.addChild(MySprite);

                        stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, touchHandler);
                        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, removeTouch);
                }

                private function touchHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
                {
                        //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, touchHandler);
                        trace("Screen Touched");
                        this.touchDown = true;
                        trace (this.touchDown);

                        if (touchDown == true && e.stageX > 160)
                          moveCharacterRight ();
                        if (touchDown == true && e.stageX < 160)
                          moveCharacterLeft ();  
                  }


                private function removeTouch(e:MouseEvent):void
                {
                        this.touchDown = false;
                        trace("Screen Released");
                        trace (this.touchDown);
                }

                private function moveCharacterRight():void
                {
                    addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, movitRight)
                    function movitRight(e)
                        {
                                MySprite.x += 10;
                                if (touchDown == false){removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movitRight)}
                        }
                }

                private function moveCharacterLeft():void
                {
                    addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, movitLeft)
                    function movitLeft(e)
                        {
                                MySprite.x -= 10;
                                if (touchDown == false){removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movitLeft)}
                        }
                }

        }
}
```

I've made it a little too verbose, for clarity. Can you figure out how to simplify it?

Comment: I'm sure I can but I don't use frames or movie clips. Will this still work? I'm using flashDevelop.

Comment: Who said anything about 'frames'? Put the exact code I gave you into FlashDevelop and run it! If your're using the Flash IDE for a library for your graphics, set the code as your document class.

Comment: I just assumed that frames were necessary given that you add an event listener for Event.ENTER_FRAME. I'll try this out.

Comment: addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ... )is just a way to tell Flash to keep looping through all the frames (even if there's only ONE) and re-drawing them. Generally you stop the loop, with a removeEventListener(...  ) when you've got what you want.